# Second QueryDefs.SQL doesn't work

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have code in Access VBA, that's fill query template with SQL and execute it. I have to querydefs. First is working fine, but with second when I assign SQL string I got error 3305.

Both of inserted tables are on Oracle DB and I have linked tables to it.

code

```
Sub prc()
Dim pSQLStr      As String        
Dim pQuery       As QueryDef   
Dim pBaza        As Database  

Set pBaza = CurrentDb
Set pQuery = pBaza.QueryDefs("qryInsertTemplate")

pSQLStr = ""
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & "INSERT INTO tbl1 ("
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & "ID, POS)"
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & "SELECT xlsx.ID, xlsx.pos"    
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & " FROM xlsx;"

With pQuery
    .SQL = pSQLStr
    .ReturnsRecords = False
    .Execute
End With

Set pQuery = pBaza.QueryDefs("qryInsertTemplate")

pSQLStr = ""
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & "INSERT INTO tbl2 ("
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & "ID, POS)"
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & "SELECT xlsx.ID, xlsx.pos"    
pSQLStr = pSQLStr & " FROM xlsx;"

With pQuery
    .SQL = pSQLStr 'here I got error 3305
    .ReturnsRecords = False
    .Execute
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you can reverse the queries' sequence, it could be that the Excel file isn't closed properly. Assuming that query two works when run stand-alone.

Comment: Stand-alone It's runing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try - before running the second time - to close the object:

```
pQuery.Close
Set pQuery = Nothing
Set pQuery = pBaza.QueryDefs("qryInsertTemplate")
```

or create a copy of qryInsertTemplate and run that the second time:

```
Set pQuery = pBaza.QueryDefs("qryInsertTemplateCopy")
```

Comment: Thanks, second solutions helped.